# How to get all checked selected items from Listview in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I want to get all the items in a listview that the checkbox has checked.

[image: lvwStudent]

```
      <ListView  x:Name="lvwStudent"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn  Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="cboxSelected" Content ="{Binding ID}"   Width="20" Height="20" BorderBrush="#FF0C6161" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="cboxSelected_Checked_1" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="NO." Width="53">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Label Content ="{Binding ID}" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="STUDENT NAME" Width="auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content ="{Binding STUDENT_NAME}" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

when I click the select button I want to get all selected ID and store in an array.

```
    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       int[] selectedId;

        if(lvwMachine.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach(..... )
            {
              //add all selected id in array selectedId


            }
         }
```

---

```
List<Student>StudentList = new Students().getStudent();
List<ListViewItem> ITEM = new List<ListViewItem>(); 

foreach (var s in StudentList) 
{ 
       ListViewItem OneItem = new ListViewItem(); 
       OneItem.Content = new Student() 
           {ID = s.ID, STUDENT_NAME = s.name}; 

       ITEM.Add(OneItem); 
       lvwMachine.ItemsSource = ITEM; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried making `{Binding IsChecked}` two-way ? It might actually be two-way bay default.. see if the IsChecked property on your view model is not set to true

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It is two-way by default.

Comment: OP, how are you populating your listbox? You should be giving lvwStudent.ItemsSource an ObservableCollection of some item type. Please show us that code.

Comment: List<Student>StudentList = new Students().getStudent();
            List<ListViewItem> ITEM = new List<ListViewItem>();
temsSource = null;
            foreach (var s in StudentList)
            {

                ListViewItem OneItem = new ListViewItem();

                OneItem.Content = new Student() { ID = s.ID, STUDENT_NAME = s.name};
             
                ITEM.Add(OneItem);
                lvwMachine.ItemsSource = ITEM;

            }

Comment: @Angela Can you read that? I can't. Please paste it into the question so it can be found and read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lvwMachine.ItemsSource.Where(element => element.IsChecked).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Angela you're missing "using System.Linq".